# NextJS - how to configure proxy to log api requests and responses?

Tags: proxy, next.js, cloudinary, charles-proxy

I am having an issue with the Cloudinary Node SDK where the Admin Resources endpoint is occasionally throwing a 302 error. Their support suggested that I proxy the request so that I can log the response between my api and their SDK and ultimately get a better idea of what might be causing the problem (in the end they're hoping to see the Location headers that are in the Response).

One of their suggestions was to use Charles Proxy, however I'm very new to how this works and am unable to figure it out. I've read through the Charles docs and spent a full day googling, but I can't find any info related to proxying between the NextJS API and Cloudinary SDK specifically.

How do I go about setting up Charles Proxy so that I can see the request and response in this way? Is there another way that I don't know of that would work instead? Since I'm using the newest version of NextJS v12, could I use the new _middleware option instead? In a later suggestion, their Support made this comment too:

```
if you can't proxy requests to localhost, you may be able to use a local DNS server or a local override so you can access your local IP using a different hostname (e.g. using /etc/hosts on a unix environment, or C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts on a windows PC) and have that proxied - that said, there's probably an easier way using a Node project or adjusting the settings of the Node server.
```

but I have no idea where to begin with this either.

Here is the api code I have:
*pages/api/auth/images.ts*

```ts
import type { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from 'next';
import cloudinary from 'cloudinary';
require('dotenv').config();

export default async function handler(_: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) {
  cloudinary.v2.config({
    cloud_name: process.env.CLOUDINARY_CLOUD_NAME,
    api_key: process.env.CLOUDINARY_API_KEY,
    api_secret: process.env.CLOUDINARY_API_SECRET,
    secure: true,
  });

  try {
    // fetch cloudinary auth images
    const response = await cloudinary.v2.api.resources({
      type: 'upload',
      prefix: 'my_app/auth_pages',
      max_results: 20,
    });

    // fetch random image
    const randImage =
      response.resources[~~(response?.resources?.length * Math.random())];

    // return image
    return res.status(200).json({ image: randImage });
  } catch (error) {
    console.dir({ error }, { colors: true, depth: null });
    return res.status(500).json({ error });
  }
}
```

Note: I'm on a Mac.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
export default async function handler(_: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) {
  cloudinary.v2.config({
    cloud_name: process.env.CLOUDINARY_CLOUD_NAME,
    api_key: process.env.CLOUDINARY_API_KEY,
    api_secret: process.env.CLOUDINARY_API_SECRET,
    api_proxy: 'http://<local_ip>:<charles_port>', //change accordingly
    secure: true,
  });
```

To get the port number, In Charles Proxy go to Proxy > Proxy Settings.

[image]